# get element horizontal position on the screen

Tags: jquery

I have this menu jquery function:

```
$("#text").click(function(evt) {
    $("#menu").css({
        top: 45,
        left: evt.pageX
    }).toggle();
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

It works ok, but the MENU opens right above the mouse click, if I click in letter k (from clicK) it opens above K.

I want it to open **always** it the same line as #text div as image above:

[image]

what I need to change? any ideas to put it fixed?

https://jsfiddle.net/z4ugf5ru/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `offset()` jq method instead to *get&set* the relevant `left` property:

```
$("#text").click(function(evt) {
    $("#menu").css({
        top: 45, // or not hardcoded: $(this).offset().top + 45,
        left: $(this).offset().left
    }).toggle();
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: That's easy for @A.Wolff

Comment: @RickJoe that's for sure it is working hope you accept it as an answer for your asked question.

Comment: @Jai Thx for your kind words :)